How to add gitignore for multi folder files
How to ignore files in the following directory structure as well as specific file.
also to untrack the .gitnore file itself.
Folder1/Folder2/hello.txt
Folder1/Folder2/text.exe
Thanks,
James

This is a non sens to add the .gitignore to itself ..

What do you mean? You want to ignore a whole directory?

I am trying to test to untrack .gitignore, eventhough it do not make any sense.

In my scenerio the file been already commited once, so for git to discard make sure the below steps are followed.
Step1
Add the line Folder1/Folder2/hello.txt to the gitignore file
Step2
Go to the git terminal and type the below
git rm --cached Folder1/Folder2/hello.txt
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "Ignore sFolder1/Folder2/hello.txt""
Step3
Confirming the File is Ignored, type the below command.
git status
Your files will not be there in the list of tracked files.
HTH
George

The .gitignore file is basically a text file which references intentionally un-tracked files and directories. You can specify some complex rules (see the full manual here or the examples here).
Let's consider your specific case: ignore the .gitignore.

If your .gitignore is already tracked, any changes to it (even if it references itself) will be shown as un-staged. This is because the file is already tracked and git considers the .gitignore for un-tracked files/directories only.

In order to get rid of the .gitignore file, simply remove it from your source tree and commit the change. Then, git will keep considering the local .gitignore (if it exists) but it will no longer tell you about it.
$ mv .gitignore .gitignore.bkp
$ git rm .gitignore
$ git commit -m "remove gitignore definition file"
$ mv .gitignore.bkp .gitignore
$ git status

$ echo ".gitigore" >> .gitignore
$ git status

Note that if you clone your repo again without copying that backed .gitignore, you will most likely see previously ignored files and directories sooner or later in the git status.

If your .gitignore is not already tracked, then git will not show it as an un-tracked file because it references itself. This is not a file that you will be able to share with other developers through git later (unless you remove the reference to itself).

In any case:

removing a non-empty .gitignore from the commit tree will discard any previously ignored files and directories.
ignoring the .gitignore will prevent you from sharing (with other developers) latter files and directories to be ignored (i.e.:every clone will have to have a local .gitignore).

This is definitely not something you want to do! Since this file is optional you may rather want not to have it than ignoring it. As stated in my comment, this use-case is a non-sens ..

Thanks Jib, for explaining in details about the gitignore file, looks like you covered every detail on it. btw can you please comment on the format for the folder in gitignore in my actual question. I appreciate all you all help
